# Sinatra app is not starting the internal webserver

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I have a very simple Sinatra app to test.

```
ubuntu@ip:~/helloworld$ cat app.rb
# app.rb
require 'sinatra'

class HelloWorldApp < Sinatra::Base
  get '/' do
    "Hello, world!"
  end
end
ubuntu@:~/helloworld$ cat config.ru
# config.ru
require './app'
run HelloWorldApp
```

When I start it on Ubuntu, it runs like this. It is not starting the listener.
Or the webserver

```
$ rackup
[2016-03-18 22:23:58] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2016-03-18 22:23:58] INFO  ruby 2.2.3 (2015-08-18) [x86_64-linux]
[2016-03-18 22:23:58] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=18049 port=9292
```

Or this way

```
$ ruby app.rb
[2016-03-18 22:28:00] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2016-03-18 22:28:00] INFO  ruby 2.2.3 (2015-08-18) [x86_64-linux]
== Sinatra (v1.4.7) has taken the stage on 4567 for development with backup from WEBrick
[2016-03-18 22:28:00] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=18087 port=4567
```

Where as on a Mac, when I start the an app, it runs like this.

```
$ ruby app.rb
== Sinatra (v1.4.7) has taken the stage on 4567 for development with backup from Thin
>> Thin web server (v1.3.1 codename Triple Espresso)
>> Maximum connections set to 1024
>> Listening on localhost:4567, CTRL+C to stop
```

It is listening on Localhost. What's the problem with my Ubuntu that it is not able to start the internal webserver. Any troubleshooting instructions?

Comment: Do you mean why is it running with Thin on your Mac but with Webrick on Ubuntu?

Comment: Yes, it is running with Thin on Mac and it is listening on a particular host and port. But with webrick, it is unable to listen to a particular host / port.

Comment: It is starting, see the lines `[2016-03-18 22:23:58] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=18049 port=9292`. Are you trying to access the server from another machine when you run on Ubuntu?

Comment: Yes, I tried to access it from same machine and also from a different machine. I am unable to. I would like to run it on 0.0.0.0 and on port 8080.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there are a couple of things going on here.

First, Thin versus Webrick. Rack and Sinatra will both try to find a suitable webserver to use when starting. They will look for Thin, but if it is not available they will both fall back to using Webrick. The solution is to install Thin on your Ubuntu server with `gem install thin`. You might want to look into using [Bundler](http://bundler.io/) and adding the `thin` gem to it to ensure you always have the same gems in development and production.

Second, accessing the server from another machine. By default, when starting up in development mode both [`rackup`](https://github.com/rack/rack/commit/28b014484a8ac0bbb388e7eaeeef159598ec64fc) and [Sinatra’s built in server](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/commit/0f9a959253bdf0c39422ffb9b60278df46ef0248) will only listen to `localhost`. To bind to `0.0.0.0` you will either need to specify the host explicitly (either with the `-o` option to `rackup` or with `set :bind '0.0.0.0'` for the Sinatra built in sever), or start in [production mode using the `RACK_ENV` environment variable](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Environments).

One additional thing – in your current setup running `ruby app.rb` won’t actually start your application. It will run the default `Sinatra::Application` (which in this case is empty) rather than your `HelloWorldApp`, since you are using the [modular style](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Sinatra::Base%20-%20Middleware,%20Libraries,%20and%20Modular%20Apps). To get this to run as you expect you should change your require line to

```
require 'sinatra/base'
```

and add

```
HelloWorldApp.run! if app_file == $0
```

to the end of the file.